# The complexity of an optimization problem involving sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, binomial-coefficients, integer-programming

I'm just new to this community. So please forgive me if the question is not properly asked.

I would like to get the natural number e such that the following function can be minimized:

$f(e)=\frac{b}{(e+a)\cdot (e+n)}\cdot \sum_{i=e}^{n+e}\begin{pmatrix}
n+e\\ i 
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot (1-p)^i\cdot p^{n+e-i} +g(e)$,

where a, b are positive constants, p represents some probability, and n is a given natural number. g(e) is a linear function which monotonically increases along with e.

The shape of the function could be 
[(Shape 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INmyt.png) or [(Shape 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPdlB.png) depends on a, b, p, n and g(e) (The function is discrete, but it is drawn continuously for convenience.). Note that the function is non-convex and there are some oscillations around the minimum point.

I intend to apply a computational algorithm to search the optimal e. But don't know what algorithm can efficiently solve it. When I tried to figure out the the complexity of the problem is. I can only see: 
1) the problem is non-linear / non-quadratic;
2) the problem is non-convex;
3) the function is non-derivable, since the function is discrete.

If the problem is too complex to be solved within polynomial time, is there any approximation approach which can reduce the complexity of the problem (if yes, what is the error)? Or I have to use a heuristic algorithm to search for the optimal e?

Comment: Anyone can help me???

Comment: Quick remark, you can make it derivable, by using the Gamma function, but I think it won't help you at all here. Personally, I would use heuristics. But you can try to use heuristics as little  as possible, for instance by lower bounding your function for some interval.

Comment: Hi Willie, thanks for your reply and I agree with your idea on heuristic approach. I converted the function by applying a smoothing function on it. Then, the curve of the function becomes more smooth such that in most case, it is convex. Even in the case that it has multiple local minima, they are quite close to the global minimum, which is good enough to my problem.